# Choose your own adventure

Tags: c

So I am making the boss room part of a choose your own adventure program and I am having issues getting the if statements to work properly. When a 1 or 2 is typed the print statements do not print.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
int main()
{
int answer;
bool repeat= true;
printf("\nYou have entered the boss room!!\nWould you like to turn back and allow humanity to be \e[1;31mDESTROYED \e[0m\n \t\tor \n\e[1;31mFIGHT\e[0m the boss and attempt to save the world?\n1.Turn back\n2.Fight\n");
while(repeat) 
{   
    if(scanf("%d",&answer) != 1 || scanf("%d",&answer) != 2)
    {
        printf("Invalid selection. Please selection an action to take.\n");
        printf("1.Turn back\n2.Fight\n");
    } 
    else if(scanf("%d",&answer) == 1) //add string option
    {
        printf("\nYou have choosen to turn back and as a result the world has been destroyed and humanity has perished!!\n\n\t\t\e[1;31mGAME OVER\e[0m\n\n");
        repeat= false;
    }
    else if(scanf("%d",&answer) == 2) //add string option
    {
        printf("\nYou have chosen to fight the boss. The fate of humanity will now be decided. Good luck.\n");    
        repeat= false;
    }  
}   
return 0;
}
```

Comment: You should use how to use [`scanf()`](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/scanf.3.html). The returned values are not the input but the number of input (how many input).

Answer (score 1):

The return value of `scanf` is the number of parameters it successfully found, so your tests are incorrect.  You would need to check if `scanf` returned 1, meaning it decoded an integer successfully, and then test the value of `answer` for either 1 or 2.

However, you'll still have a problem if the user types something that isn't an integer, like `1.1` or `I like pie`.  Then the input buffer will still contain the original input and your code will loop forever.  In cases like this, you'd need to clear the input buffer before calling `scanf` again in the loop.  It is this weakness of `scanf` (among others) that make people not like it.

What you can do instead is use a function like `fgets` to read the entire input as a string, thus clearing all the input every time, and then parse that string further with `sscanf` or similar.  This way you can keep your same loop and test structure and not have  to worry about non-conforming input making your loop iterate forever.

I have rewritten your code showing one way to manage input via `fgets`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
int main()
{
   char line[80];
   int answer;
   printf("\nYou have entered the boss room!!\nWould you like to turn back and allow humanity to be \e[1;31mDESTROYED \e[0m\n \t\tor \n\e[1;31mFIGHT\e[0m the boss and attempt to save the world?\n1.Turn back\n2.Fight\n");
   while(fgets(line, 80, stdin) != NULL) 
   {
        if(sscanf(line,"%d",&answer) != 1 || (answer != 1 && answer != 2))
        {
            printf("Invalid selection. Please selection an action to take.\n");
            printf("1.Turn back\n2.Fight\n");
        }
        else if(answer == 1) //add string option
        {
            printf("\nYou have choosen to turn back and as a result the world has been destroyed and humanity has perished!!\n\n\t\t\e[1;31mGAME OVER\e[0m\n\n");
            break;
        }
        else // answer == 2  //add string option
        {
            printf("\nYou have chosen to fight the boss. The fate of humanity will now be decided. Good luck.\n");    
            break;
        }  
   }   
   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

- Input is read in each time `scanf()` is called.
- The return value of `scanf()` is not the value read but the number of input (how many data are read).

Instead of calling `scanf()` many times like this, you should read once and use that value for conditions.

Also note that the condition `answer != 1 || answer != 2` will always be true because no number is equal to both 1 and 2 at the same time. It should be `answer != 1 && answer != 2`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
int main()
{
    int answer;
    bool repeat= true;
    printf("\nYou have entered the boss room!!\nWould you like to turn back and allow humanity to be \e[1;31mDESTROYED \e[0m\n \t\tor \n\e[1;31mFIGHT\e[0m the boss and attempt to save the world?\n1.Turn back\n2.Fight\n");
    while(repeat) 
    {
        if(scanf("%d",&answer) != 1) // read a value
        {
            puts("read error");
            return 1;
        }
        if(answer != 1 && answer != 2)
        {
            printf("Invalid selection. Please selection an action to take.\n");
            printf("1.Turn back\n2.Fight\n");
        } 
        else if(answer == 1) //add string option
        {
            printf("\nYou have choosen to turn back and as a result the world has been destroyed and humanity has perished!!\n\n\t\t\e[1;31mGAME OVER\e[0m\n\n");
            repeat= false;
        }
        else if(answer == 2) //add string option
        {
            printf("\nYou have chosen to fight the boss. The fate of humanity will now be decided. Good luck.\n");    
            repeat= false;
        }  
    }
    return 0;
}
```